# What is the source of creativity and intellect according to the scriptures?

Tags: scripture

I have always been fascinated by human creativity and intellect. Their achievements in science, architecture, art, storytelling etc is truly inspiring but not all can achieve these feats. Is their any verses in the scriptures addressing these topics like intellect and creativity and their origin and why not all are equal in these?